# how to unlist a list of regression models in R

Tags: r, list, model, regression

I fitted a several models on a single variable (a) as a mod1. Output mod1 contains regression fitting list of the 5 models. I did several operation in the list of models. Now I want to unlist mod1 into a single regression model output like fit1, fit2,...fit5 etc.

```
func <-function(z){
  fit1 <- lm( y~ x + z )
  fit2 <- lm( y~x + I(z^2))
  fit3 <- lm( y~poly(x,3) + z)
  fit4 <- lm( y~ns(x, 3) + z)
  fit5 <- lm( y~ns(x, 9) + z)
  return(list(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, fit5))
}

mod1 <- func(data$a) 

test <- unlist(mod1, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
```

When I used unlist(), output turned very long un-understandable strings. Even when I tried this following, it is still a list of 1 model.

```
fit1 <- mod1[1]
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to separate models one by one from a list of regression model output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into the `broom` package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Comment: Thank you! I just saw it. I don't get how to use it because it is all about running a single regression model and get their statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a combination of using `broom` to tidy the output of `lm`, and standard list methods `lapply` and `[[` indexing to work with lists.

Read more about working with lists in R [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#lists).

```
library(splines)

# create some example data
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                y = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                z = rnorm(100, 0, 1))

# function to fit 5 models
func <-function(d){
  fit1 <- lm( y~ x + z, data = d)
  fit2 <- lm( y~x + I(z^2), data = d)
  fit3 <- lm( y~poly(x,3) + z, data = d)
  fit4 <- lm( y~ns(x, 3) + z, data = d)
  fit5 <- lm( y~ns(x, 9) + z, data = d)

  # store models in a list
  l <- list(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, fit5)

  # name the models
  names(l) <- paste0("fit", 1:5) 

  return(l)
}

# run the function
mods <- func(d)
```

Access each element of the list with double brackets `[[`

```
mods[[1]]

Call:
  lm(formula = y ~ x + z, data = d)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)            x            z  
0.03339     -0.05128     -0.15288  

mods[[2]]

Call:
  lm(formula = y ~ x + I(z^2), data = d)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)            x       I(z^2)  
0.01739     -0.04490      0.01258
```

Use broom to "tidy" model output

```
library(broom)
tidy(mods[[1]])

# A tibble: 3 x 5
term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
<chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
  1 (Intercept)   0.0334    0.0985     0.339   0.735
2 x            -0.0513    0.103     -0.499   0.619
3 z            -0.153     0.102     -1.50    0.138
```

Use `lapply` (or `purrr::map`) to tidy the list of model output.

```
tidy_mods <- lapply(mods, tidy) 

# add names to each data frame and combine into one big data frame
for(i in 1:length(tidy_mods)) tidy_mods[[i]]$mod <- names(tidy_mods[i])
do.call(rbind.data.frame, tidy_mods)

# A tibble: 27 x 6
term        estimate std.error statistic p.value mod  
* <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
  1 (Intercept)   0.0334    0.0985     0.339  0.735  fit1 
2 x            -0.0513    0.103     -0.499  0.619  fit1 
3 z            -0.153     0.102     -1.50   0.138  fit1 
4 (Intercept)   0.0174    0.130      0.134  0.894  fit2 
5 x            -0.0449    0.105     -0.429  0.669  fit2 
6 I(z^2)        0.0126    0.0894     0.141  0.888  fit2 
7 (Intercept)   0.0309    0.0975     0.317  0.752  fit3 
8 poly(x, 3)1  -0.493     0.975     -0.505  0.614  fit3 
9 poly(x, 3)2  -0.569     0.975     -0.584  0.561  fit3 
10 poly(x, 3)3   1.78      0.976      1.83   0.0709 fit3
```